# Compiling Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces

When I am trying to compile this code

```
using namespace std;
namespace asf{
inline int operator|(int);
}

asf::operator|(int x){
return (x>1)?x*operator|(x-1):1;
}

int main(){
    cout<<5|;
}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
[Error] 'int asf::operator|(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
[Error] ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'operator|' with no type [-fpermissive]
[Error] 'int asf::operator|(int)' should have been declared inside 'asf'
[Error] 'int asf::operator|(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
In function 'int main()':
[Error] expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

What is wrong? Please help.

Comment: You can't override `|` on `int`s. Besides, `|` is a binary operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, overloaded operators must have at least one argument of class or enumerated type. That's how the language works.

In addition, you cannot change the arity of an operator when overloading. You're tryning to define a unary `|`, which is also illegal. `|` must always take two arguments. The declaration of `operator |` can include one argument only if it's declared inside a class, in which case the left-hand operand is implicitly of the class's type.

Comment: suppose i change the symbol, i.e i dont overload, then? and can I use this  operator!! maybe?

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha you cannot define your own operators (At least not in the classic way, there are some hacks, but they are not recommended)